# Start a Docker container with a user permission and a USB device

Tags: python, opencv, docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I created a very simple script that takes pictures on a Raspberry Pi (RPi) using a USB camera.

To help to deploy on more than one RPi I wanted to use Docker.

Sometimes I make an image that does exactly what I want: I take a picture every T time then save on a host partition that I mounted when I started the container. (BTW, it uses Python and [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).)

I want to send those pictures on my main computer, so I wanted the images to have the permission of the user that I use to log in on the RPi.

So when I create the container I use something like this:

```
docker run -d --name container_name \
       -v /home/user/images:/home/images \
       -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
       --device /dev/video0 \
       image_name
```

It does create directories and files with the user permission, **BUT** I can't read the USB camera any more.

If I remove the `-u` argument I can read the camera, but the files/directories are created **as root**, which causes a problem to retrieve the images after.

I tried first to make a swarm (to update the image more easily), but I reached difficulties to use devices with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the required access rights to the device? They are usually accessible by groups. Running using `-u` will only set your user with the group returned by `id -g`.

I also access devices and create files from a development-only container and solved this problem by creating a dedicated user within the container, including the required groups to access the devices.

Here is how I create this user for my development container in the Dockerfile:

```
# Create a non-root user with the same uid as on the host to allow proper file
# permissions created from the container in volumes. Since it is not root, allow
# calling sudo without password when required.
ARG uid
RUN useradd -M --uid $uid --user-group user --groups uucp \
    && echo 'user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/user \
    && echo 'Defaults exempt_group+=user' >> /etc/sudoers.d/user \
    && chmod a=r,o= /etc/sudoers.d/user
USER user
```

These dockerfile instructions create a non-root user, with its own user group, and includes it in the `uucp` group to access TTY devices in Debian. The user id is passed as a Docker build argument (instruction `ARG uid`, plus Docker build option `--build-arg uid=$(id -u)`). I then add it as sudoer without a password (mostly to be able to sometimes run package management commands and try a few things).